# No CustomerOrder matches the query

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying the generate PDF's for customers who successfully pays for an item but I keep getting this error.

**No CustomerOrder matches the query**

Below are my codes.

views.py

```
@staff_member_required
def admin_order_pdf(request, order_id):
    order = get_object_or_404(CustomerOrder, id=order_id)
    html = render_to_string('orders/pdf.html', {'order': order})
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'filename=order_{order_id}.pdf'
    weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response, stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATIC_ROOT + 'css/pdf.css')])
    return response
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.order_payout, name='order_payout'),
    path('admin/order/<int:order_id>/pdf', views.admin_order_pdf, name='admin_order_pdf'),
    path('confirm/', views.confirm_order, name='confirm_order'),
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The get_object_or_404 method returns the message 'No object matches the given query' when it is unable to find any objects in the specified model using the given filter, which is **id=order_id** in this case.
Check [this section from the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) for more information on the function.